# Poles Zeros Plot in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats

basically I want to copy this pzmap.

[image]

I tried to draw the complex plane but now I am stuck, any suggestions?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Axes:
\draw [->] (-7,0) -- (2,0) node [above left]  {$\Re$};
\draw [->] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node [below right] {$\Im$};



\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: circle: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/124064/124842 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/282047/124842, cross: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40527/124842  , sin or cos value: like `\draw[gray, dashed] (0,0)--({-cos(60)},{sin(60)});` angle: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219039/124842

Comment: arrow head: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5467/124842

Comment: also in case you are being tortured still  here is root locus https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213183/root-locus-plots-using-latex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% Axes:
\draw [-latex] (-7,0) -- (2,0) node [above left]  {$\Re$};
\draw [-latex] (0,-5) -- (0,5) node [below right] {$\Im$};
\node[cross out,draw=black] at (0,0) {};
\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- node[pos=0.8, above right] {$\omega_p$}(145:6) node[solid, cross out,draw=black] {};
\draw[red, -stealth] (0,2) arc (90:145:2);

\draw[dashed] (0,0) -- node[pos=0.8, above right] {$\omega_z$}(125:3.5) node[solid, fill=white, circle,draw=black] {};
\draw[blue, -stealth] (0,1) arc (90:125:1);

\draw[dashed]  (-5,0) node[below left] {$-\xi_p\omega_p$} --  (-5,-3) node[solid, cross out,draw=black] {};
\draw[dashed]  (-2,0) node[below left] {$-\xi_z\omega_z$} --  (-2,-3) node[solid, fill=white, circle,draw=black] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]